# Passing Variable from Function in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

If you have the following function:

```
def foo(a):
   b = a + 1
   c = a + 2
   return b, c
foo(1)
```

How do you make it so that you can call the variables generated in the function (`b` and `c`) later in the code. i.e) `print b, c`?

EDIT: Changed to MCVE

Comment: this is not a code review board. Please make a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question

Comment: Sorry about that, just changed it. Is this more appropriate?

Comment: nice, that is exactly what a MCVE is (and will get an upvote for the effort from me) - however there is probably an answer to that somwhere on SO. You should in any case read this: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html about writing idiomatic python, which will help you understanding the language basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rate, num_samples, dur, num_chans = extract_vars(blks)

# your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `tuple`, so as Mr E said, you'd want to call it like this:

```
rate, num_samples, dur, num_chans = extract_vars(blks)
```

Then in the function that calls `extract_vars()`, `rate`, `num_samples`, `dur`, and `num_chans` will all be available - so you could `print dur`.